# Spring Boot JMS MappingJackson2MessageConverter cannot find `_type` field even though it exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I'm using Spring boot to receive JMS message and cURL to send it.

Here's the Spring config:

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}
```

When I try to send a message, I get:

`org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not find type id property [_type] on message [ID:b5151b422e8a-41371-1526292561432-6:3:1:1:14] from destination [queue://ssg]`

My cURL command is:

`curl -u 'un:pw' -H '_type: com.me.SSMessage' -d 'body={"_type": "com.me.SSMessage", "url": "https://www.google.com"}' "http://localhost:8161/api/message/ssg?type=queue&clientId=consumerA"`

`_type` is set, both as a header (I don't think this is right) and as a field in the JSON.  Why do I get that error from the Spring app?

Comment: ? The JMS converter is for JMS messages; that curl command uses HTTP. If that's what you really mean, you need to show more context.

Comment: This was actually a question about Activemq and how to add a property to a message, turns out...

Comment: In your case, it is "com.me.SSMessage" but how do you generally find out what is the value of _type? (I'm not a Java developer so I may not understand if it is a path thing)

Comment: It's the fully-qualified Java class that you want the de-serializer to create from the String. This means the package & class separated by `.`, basically - see here for more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more an Activemq/REST question than Spring:

`converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");`

This sets a JMS Message property, it is not a field in the message.  The stuff about message headers is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html

The trick is how to do this with the Activemq REST interface (and thus CURL).  The answer is to add it as a `GET` parameter on the query:

```
curl -u 'un:pw' -H '_type: com.me.SSMessage' \
-d 'body={"url": "https://www.google.com"}' \ 
"http://localhost:8161/api/message/ssg? \ 
type=queue&clientId=consumerA&_type=com.me.SSMessage"
```

Edit: I can't test it, but I don't think the `-H '_type: com.me.SSMessage'` is needed above...

Comment: So how do we fix the error in the Java code?

Comment: @RaymondChen You fix the java error by providing the `_type=com.me.SSMessage` in the cURL command...